# Replace current Desktop Environment with simple GUI application

Tags: raspbian, desktop

I don't need the desktop and all the functionalities that come with it. Is it possible to replace it with a simple GUI application? So that after login I never see the desktop but instead my own application. What do I have to change to make this happen?

I'm using raspbian if this is important.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to only launch the X server with one application, you can do it using the `startx` script from the tty

```
$ startx "/usr/bin/application --key value"
```

More info on startx / xinit [on the archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit). (The archwiki is an invaluable ressource even if you are not using archlinux)

It should also be possible to configure your login screen (probably lightdm) to do so, if you want a graphical login

But honestly, if you want to avoid a heavy desktop manager, you can also use a small window manager (such as `openbox`), which won't be as heavy, but will still allow you to, for example, resize your window, or launch several applications